# How to add elements to array in JavaScript from input variables?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Sorry maybe my english is not good, 
I have a HTML file with javascript tag and send variables to java script in such way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js" class="33.870959 -118.027830 33.803498 -118.279524 34.087291 -118.259329"></script>
```

this is javascript:

```
 function initMap() 
{  var center = {lat: 34.046438, lng: -118.259653};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 9,
    center: center
  });
var params = document.body.getElementsByTagName('script');
query = params[0].classList;

var locations = [
    ['hwlo',   query[0], query[1]],
    ['hwlo',   query[2], query[3]],
    ['hwlo',   query[4], query[5]],
  ];

var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
var marker, count;
for (count = 0; count < locations.length; count++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[count][1], locations[count][2]),
      map: map,
      title: document.currentScript.getAttribute('one')
    });
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, count) {
      return function () {
        infowindow.setContent(document.currentScript.getAttribute('one'));
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, count));
  }
}
```

this is code that take arguments from html file:

```
var params = document.body.getElementsByTagName('script');
query = params[0].classList;

var locations = [
    ['hwlo',   query[0], query[1]],
    ['hwlo',   query[2], query[3]],
    ['hwlo',   query[4], query[5]],
  ];
```

I want to change "var locations" to code, that would generate array dynamically, depends of how many arguments "33.870959 -118.027830 33.803498 -118.279524 ....." pass from html file.

Comment: those are not a valid class name

Comment: Naming rules:

Must begin with a letter A-Z or a-z
Can be followed by: letters (A-Za-z), digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"), and underscores ("_")

Comment: thanks for your advice. I am not good in Javascript and this is one of my firtst programming experience in this language